# I created a Modal using createPortal() method to render it. Then I found that modal renders twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-modal, react-portal

When the button inside the Post clicked, Popup will render with createPortal method outside from root element's tree.

With this code that popup renders twice.

I want to render it only once.

Here's the parent Post component.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import PopupModal from './PopupModal/PopupModal';
import './Post.css';
    const Post = (props) => {
        const postData = props;
    
        const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
        return (
            <div className="post-container">
                <div className="post-img-container">
                    <img className="post-img" src={props.img} alt="Travels" />
                </div>
                <div className="post-text-container">
                    <h4 className="post-heading">{props.title}</h4>
                    <p className="post-para">{props.description}</p>
                    <h1 className="post-price">{props.price}</h1>
                    <div className="post-btn-container">
                        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} className="post-btn">
                            Check Availability
                        </button>
                        <PopupModal dataData={postData} open={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
                            Button123
                        </PopupModal>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    
    export default Post;
```

> ```
> And here's the popupModal
> ```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../PopupModal/popupModal.css'

const MODAL_STYLES = {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)',
    background: '#fff',
    width: '40vw',
    height: '90vh',
    padding: '50px',
    zIndex: 1000,
};

const PopupModal = ({ open, children, onClose ,dataData }) => {
    if (!open) return null;

    console.log('xxx');
    console.log(dataData);

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <>
            <div className='modal-overlay' ></div>
            <div className='modal-container'>
                <button onClick={onClose}> Popup Close</button>
                {children}
            </div>
        </>,
        document.getElementById('portal')
    );
};

export default PopupModal;
```

Here's how I figured it rendered twice.

[image]

Here's the Popup with overlay around it which covers the background.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
{
     isOpen && <PopupModal dataData={postData} open={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
                   Button123
               </PopupModal> 
}
```